# Entity Framework Core connection management

Tags: .net, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In an asp.net core project, I need an encrypted SQLite database. For that, I made my own `SqliteEncryptedConnection` which inherits from `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection` and which sets the encryption key in the `Open()` method (execute PRAGMA key = ...)

I have an extension method that configures my EF context by creating a connection and giving it.

```
    public static void UseEncryptedSqlite(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, string connectionString, string password)
    {
        var connection = new SqliteEncryptedConnection(connectionString, password);
        connection.Open();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connection);
    }
```

I must open the connection before I give it to EF, otherwise it is automatically opened and closed by EF for each single query, and the `Open()` method is now quite expensive.

My problem with this solution is that my connection is never disposed nor closed!

1. Is it correct to set the encryption key in Open?
2. Is there a way to know when the context is disposed? Or to configure it to close and dispose the connection after it is disposed?
3. Is there another (better) way to manage the connection?

The dirty solution would be to dispose the connection in the EF context's Dispose method, but I don't really want to dispose a dependency that was injected and not owned by the context.

Comment: Its by the design if I understand your issue correctly. The `DbContextOptions` object won't be disposed and will be reused for all instances of EF Core DbContext, since the options is passed to the DbContext when it gets initialized. Since 2.0 preview1, even DbContext instances can be polled for high performance scenarions, see this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/12/announcing-ef-core-2-0-preview-1/)

Comment: @Tseng The connection is not re-used. This method is called each time a new DbContext is injected. -> 1 per web request.

Fortunately these connections seem to be correctly garbage collected. So, finally, I don't know if it is a problem if dispose/close is not called before the garbage collection occurs.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue with the connection not being closed by EF Core context if it receives it already open. In my case I cannot pass it closed in the options object because I need a connection in a sharded environment and this is how I receive it from the `OpenConnectionForKey` method of the `ShardMap` object.

Comment: @AdrianPavel I answered my question with the response I got from Brice Lambson. In your case if the connection is used by a single context, it is safe to dispose it in the context `Dispose` method

Answer (score 5):

I had an answer from Brice Lambson who works in the EF core team:

> You're going in the right direction--open connections less. Remember,
>   SQLite connections are essentially just file streams, so keeping them
>   open longer isn't really an issue.
>
> **If there's only ever one DbContext instance per connection, the
>   DbContext can still own the connection even if it's created
>   externally. Just dispose the connection inside of DbContext.Dispose().**
>
> If that's not enough, you could try creating a connection pool.
>   Managing the lifetime might get tricky. The important thing is that a
>   connection doesn't get used outside of the thread it was created on.
>
> Using Cache=Shared (i.e. [Shared-Cache Mode](https://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html)) might also help
>   throughput.

Comment: I have a similar situation, where by adding password protected Sqlite connection I notice a drastic performance issue. Did you experience the same? If so what did you do to fix it?